# Como comparar diferentes arrays de las $_session

Tags: php, mysqli, session

Estoy intentando realizar una comparación luego del `session_start();`

Lo que estuve pensando e intentando realizar es:

```
<?php
  session_start();
    if($_SESSION['id_usuario']=NULL) {
       $_SESSION['id_nivel']=3;
           if($_SESSION['id_usuario']= 'X') {
          }
      }
   else {
     header("Location: register.php");
   }
?>
```

*¿Existe la posibilidad de hacerlo? ¿Alguna ayuda para lograrlo?*

Comment: En el if es comparación , no asignación `if($_SESSION['id_usuario']===NULL) { ...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando comparas valores en una condición se hace con `==` o `===` , lo que estás realizando es una asignación simplemente con `=` , entonces su código debería ser.

Ahora si desea validar que exista el usuario , podría hacerlo con `isset` directamente sobre la `$_SESSION['id_usuario']`

```
<?php
  session_start();
    if($_SESSION['id_usuario']=== NULL) {
       $_SESSION['id_nivel']=3;//asignas a 3
           if(isset($_SESSION['id_usuario']) {//Si está definido el id_usuario
             // $iduser = $_SESSION['id_usuario'];
             // $con = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id_usuario = $iduser;
             // Agregue estos comentarios con posibilidad de hacer una consulta y traer
             // los datos existentes a "X". Pero nose si esto seria lo correcto.
          }
      }
   else {
     header("Location: register.php");
   }
?>
```

Comment: @Juan No entiendo el porqué quiere compara el id del usuario ? ,no debería ser nivel? , ahora este valor del array se puede llenar en el login como mencione y ya la validación no sería por id , si no con `isset($_SESSION['id_usuario'];` , Igual no tengo claro su proceso.

Comment: Acabo de hacer ese mismo proceso de utilizar `isset()` y me ha funcionado

Comment: @Juan perfecto, actualicé mi respuesta. con ese detalle. _(limpiare los comentarios)_ Saludos.